# Angular2 - How to access value stored in data attributes

Tags: angular, custom-data-attribute

This may have been asked, but i've tried googling for sometime without having getting any solution.

I have the following select field in Angular2, how do i access the stored value in the data attribute of `attr.data-thisdata`?

```
<select #dial">
   <option *ngFor="let something of somethings"
     [value]="something.value" 
     [attr.data-thisdata]="something.data"
   >{{something.text}}</option>
</select>
```

I have tried the following but not getting any values:

1. `<select (change)="readData($event.target.dataset)>...<select>`
2. `<select (change)="readData($event.target.dataset.thisdata)>...<select>`

My readData is simply:

```
readData(data:any){
    console.log(data)
}
```

**EDIT 1**: added [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZtQEudn6wORARIUDa3VH?p=preview) for ease of reference

**EDIT 2**: included [plunker from Günter's answer](https://plnkr.co/edit/W365NL1t45t264o75tUy?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `[ngValue]` instead of value you can assign an object instead of only a string.

```
<select #dial" ngModel (ngModelChange)="$event.data">
   <option *ngFor="let something of somethings"
     [ngValue]="something" 
     [attr.data-thisdata]="something.data"
   >{{something.text}}</option>
</select>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZyMU06fH6zws6pl1TiAG?p=preview)

Comment: but `something` is only defined in the `<option *ngFor="let something of somethings">`?

Comment: it's not working, i added `readData` to your `(ngModelChange)="$event.data` i get undefined..

Comment: Can't imagine. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: yep, added the plunker

Comment: ok, i got it now, with `ngValue` and having assigned an object to it, there wont be a need to use data attribute right?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the original question of how to access a data attribute of an option element through a select element's event, use:

```
event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].dataset.thisdata
```

The reason `event.target.dataset.thisdata` does not work is the data attribute actually belongs to the option, but the event here is coming from the select element. We can access the selected option by using the select's selectedIndex property.